# Output Rhombus Sequence without Nested Loops

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, sequence

The following is the rhombus sequence.

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
12345654321
1234567654321
123456787654321
12345678987654321
```

Your task is to output this, taking no input and using standard output methods (STDOUT, list of numbers or list of strings, etc.).

There's a hitch. You may only use up to one loop - no nested loops. Recursion counts as a loop, so you can either recurse or loop, not both. Non-standard languages will be dealt with on a case-by-case basis.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program in bytes wins. This is [kolmorgorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmorgorov-complexity), so you may not take any input whatsoever.

Comment: Hey pluto, I edited your challenge to be on-topic here. Let me know if you disagree with anything I said - I think you'll get answers now though, if it gets reopened.

Comment: Appreciate the effort @StepHen! I think I should have put my question this way itself.

Comment: Does mapping over a list count as a loop?

Comment: This is a [do X without Y challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/45941), which are discouraged.

Comment: FYI: This is `1²`, `11²`, `111²`, ..., `111111111²`

Comment: @Shaggy I don't think so, this is [tag:restricted-source].

Comment: Banning loops is not a source restriction.

Comment: Is looping & recursion only banned at the highest level (explicitly instructed in the source) or should lower levels avoid them too; if so to what level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
((10^#-1)/9)^2&~Array~9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfQ8PQIE5Z11BT31IzzkitzrGoKLGyzvJ/QFFmXomCQ9p/AA)

Comment: Nice use of math formulas. I borrowed that for my Python answer too. +1

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Only one for-loop here

```
TG1N×n,
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/xN3Q7/D0PJ3//wE)

Explanation:

```
TG        # For N in range(1, 10):
  1N×     # Push a string of N 1's
     n    # Square that number
      ,   # Pop and print with a newline
```

Comment: `9LηεûJ=` counts as 1 loop or 3 loops? I guess prefixes would loop and so would range?

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to  officialaimm</sup>

```python
o=0
exec"o=o*10+1;print o*o;"*9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9/WgCu1IjVZKd82X8vQQNvQuqAoM69EIV8r31pJy/L/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>42 40 38</s> 35 bytes

*-2 thanks to @officialaimm*

I ported Jenny_mathy's Mathematica answer to Python, because the arithmetic approach is much shorter:

```python
i=1;exec"print(10**i/9)**2;i+=1;"*9
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PW0Dq1IjVZqaAoM69Ew9BASytT31JTS8vIOlMbKKekZfn/PwA)**

## Exaplanation

- `i=1` - Initializes a variable `i` to `1`.
- `exec"..."*9` - Executes `...` 9 times.
- `print(10**i/9)**2` - Prints 10 <sup>*i*</sup> and divides the result by 9, which then gets sqaured.
- `i+=1` - Increment `i` and execute again.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
for i in range(9):print(10**-~i/9)**2
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1LTqqAoM69Ew9BAS0u3LlPfUlNLC6gMAA)**

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

This is the initial version.

```python
l='123456789'
for i in l:s=l.index(i);print l[:s]+l[:s+1][::-1]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8dW3dDI2MTUzNzCUp0rLb9IIVMhM08hx6rYNkcvMy8ltUIjU9O6oCgzr0QhJ9qqOFYbRGobxkZbWekaxv7/DwA)

Comment: @officialaimm Too late, I already have 35 :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
9ŒḄ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/y6KSHO1oeNa2J/P8fAA)

This only uses one mapping loop (`€`) since `ŒḄ` (palindromize) is a builtin already. Explanation:

```
9ŒḄ€Y
9     9
   €  Map (our looping construct)
 ŒḄ     Palindromize (make range)
    Y Join by newlines.
```

Comment: ŒḄ€Y everybody, ŒB€Y!

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
9∫Δø∑ΓO
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=OSV1MjIyQiV1MDM5NCVGOCV1MjIxMSV1MDM5M08_)

Explanation:

```
9∫       do 9 times, pushing 1-indexed counter
  Δ        get 1-indexed (last inclusive) range
   ø∑      join together
     Γ     palindromise
      O    output it
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 20 bytes

```
⍪(' '~⍨∘⍕⍳,1↓⌽∘⍳)¨⍳9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtEx71rtJQV1Cve9S74lHHjEe9Ux/1btYxfNQ2@VHPXrDAZs1DK4Ck5f//AA)

**How?**

`¨⍳9` - for each in range 1..9

`⍳,` - produce the range of this number

`1↓⌽∘⍳` - appended to itself reversed without the last item

`⍕` - format to string

`' '~⍨` - remove spaces

`⍪` - output vertically

### 17 bytes, doesn't work because of precision issues

```
⌽⍕×⍨⍪(10⊥1⍴⍨⊢)¨⍳9
```

This one uses the `i` ones squared identity, but replaces the first one on the last line with a `0`, because the decoding rounds it up.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
9⟦₁{⟦₁⟨kc↔⟩cẉ}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/3/LR/GWPmhqrIdSj@Suykx@1TXk0f2Xyw12dtQ@3Tvj/HwA)

Yeah this doesn't feel much declarative...

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://vim.sourceforge.io/) + coreutils, 42 bytes

```
i1⏎12<Esc>qqYp$ylp<C-a>q6@qggqqjYpv$!rev⏎kJd2lq7@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9OQy9BIurAwskClMqeAsdDMoTA9vbAwK7KgTEWxKLWMK9srxSin0Nyh8P9/AA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
i1⏎12<Esc>                                          " start with lines 1,12 in the buffer
          qq           q6@q                         " record macro and run it 6 times:
            Yp                                      "  - duplicate line
              $ylp                                  "  - duplicate last character
                  <C-a>                             "  - increment it
                           gg                       " go to the beginning (buffer is now: 1,12,123,...,12..89)
                             qq               q7@q  " record macro and run it 6 times:
                               jYp                  "  - go to line below and duplicate it
                                  v$!rev⏎           "  - mark it and reverse it
                                         kJ         "  - join the line above with the current one
                                           d2l      "  - remove the space and character that are too much
```

[image: vim gif]

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 101 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;_=>new int[9].Select((n,i)=>"123456789".Substring(0,i+1)+"87654321".Substring(8-i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9NS8NAEL3nVyw57dJ0Mf1MaZNLUVEUijl4UJHNdiojm1nNbhSR/vaYNKAt@A7DY@a9xzzthqUl25Aqwb0pDSz/ch5KeYP0HnwHrIU2yjm2OfB@08F55VGzD4tbdquQuPg9/Yk6XNSkV7Z4Be0jtrbGtAQtOXkJBBVqeXVOdQmVKgysnK@QXrKM7VjaPKcZwSdD8g@LJ5lD5@ScIhRpFsaj8WQ6myeLUOZ10fv4WYSDWAzCZD6bTsaj@PiWDFGIZhmcPLduH7EG5H2FHtrOwHu1vLZtpfCRwojtONXGCCGWJ9Z/c@5AbQ8xR@J90M998wM)

---

Or the loop approach for 111 bytes:

```c#
_=>{var a=new string[9];for(int i=0;i<9;)a[i]="123456789".Substring(0,++i)+"87654321".Substring(9-i);return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9NS8NAEL3nVwx7ypI09LsN2/QieBAFsQcPNch2u5GRZFZ2NxUp@e0xbVBb8B2GYd4Hb5QbVIZMS7LS7kMqDZsv53UVHAPooErpHDye9/5ygvPSo4KDwT08SKSQ/1J/ohNua1Irs3vXysedyyK9bfM1FJC1r9n6eJAWZEb684dLc1EYGyJ5wGwocJUKLreYZ2w0nkxn88UyZcmm3vXycBhHEfKILRfz2XQyHl1y6QC5sNrXlkCKphXBVbMbQ86UOnm26PU9kg57X3Jnun/YC7EYipDqsuSciyvrvzlPWu7PMRfiJuhn034D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](http://www.pyth.readthedocs.io), 11 bytes

```
jm^s*d\12S9
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%5Es%2ad%5C12S9&debug=0)

---

### How does this work?

```
 m       S9         - Map over [1...9]
  ^s    2           - The square of the integer formed by:
    *d\1            - the string with n consecutive 1s.
j                   - Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>39</s> 32 bytes

No for loops/recursion at all, makes use of list comprehension:

```hs
[[1..x]++[x-1,x-2..1]|x<-[1..9]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzraUE@vIlZbO7pC11CnQtdIT88wtqbCRhckbhkb@z83MTNPwVYhN7HAN16hoCgzr0Qh7f@/5LScxPTi/7oRzgEBAA)

Comment: List of numbers is allowed output, however im not sure if **list of list of numbers** is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 69 bytes

There is only one "loop", when I iterate over `(1 to 9)`. But you could consider that there are loops in `reverse` and `Range` instanciations.

```scala
(1 to 9).map(x=>println(((1 to x)++(1 to x-1).reverse).mkString("")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQ/V/DUKEkX8FSUy83sUCjwtauoCgzryQnT0MDIlGhqa0NZekaauoVpZalFhWnAlVnB5cAVaZrKClpamr@r/0PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 66 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(Join("
",REPT(1,ROW(A1:A8))^2,"12345678987654321"))
```

No loops, just a matrix. It would only be 46 bytes but Sheets only has 15 decimal points of precision so the last number is displayed as `12345678987654300` or `1.23457E+1621` so I had to add it manually.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 55 bytes

```
a=1
Loop,9{ 
b:=a**2
Send %b%`n
a:=a 1
}
Send {VK08 2}1
```

This was too stupid of a result for me to not post. AHK messes rounds the last output to `12345678987654320` so we backspace twice and add a `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 17 bytes

```
[9|?((z^a-1)/9)^2
```

From [oeis](https://oeis.org/A002477).

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 18 bytes

```r
cumsum(10^(0:8))^2
```

Returns the values.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfX1CSmZ9XrFGcnFmQmmdraqD5P7k0t7g0V8PQIE7DwMpCUzPO6L@hkbGJqZm5haWFuZmpibGRga0tupDhfwA)

Due to floating point precision issues, the last number is `12345678987654320` which is equal to `12345678987654321` in R, as the footer shows. In the header, it sets the options to get the numbers to print in non-scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 66 bytes

Returns an array of strings representing the numbers in the sequence (necessary because 12345678987654321 is too large to be accurately represented as an int in Javascript)

```
o=>Array(9).fill``.map(x=>(x+(n=n*10+1)*n).replace(0,1),n=‌​0)
```

### Explanation

```
o=>                               // o is unused input (saves 1 byte vs ())
    Array(9)                      // create an array of length 9
        .fill``                   // fill it with empty strings
                                  // we must fill it with something, because map skips
                                  // empty entries
        .map(                     // loop over the array and return a new array with the
                                  // values returned by the callback
            x=>(                  // x is the element in the array
                (x+(n=n*10+1)*n)  // make n 1, 11, 111, 1111, etc, and get the string
                                  // value of n^2
                    .replace(0,1) // replace 0's with 1's (necessary for
                                  // 12345678987654321, because
                                  // 111111111^2 = 12345678987654320 in javascript)
            ),
            n=0                   // n^2 is the rhombus number at each stage
        )
```

Comment: -6 bytes: `o=>Array(9).fillBTBT.map(x=>(x+(n=n*10+1)*n).replace(0,1),n=0)` (replace BT with backticks)

Comment: Thanks, I should have remember the backticks bit. Apparently my golf game just wasn't on yesterday >;o)

Answer (score 0):

### [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), 46 bytes

```
(1..9).map{"1".repeat(it).toLong()}.map{it*it}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
for(;$i<9**8;)echo(($i.='1')**2)."
";
```

with warnings

## PHP, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
for($i=0;$i<9**8;)echo(($i.='1')**2)."
";
```

without warnings

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://www.swift.org), 76 bytes

```swift
import Foundation
for i in 1...9{print(Int(pow((pow(10,Double(i))-1)/9,2)))}
```

**[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/597a1340fd4af225961bf016)**

If printing as an array of lines is allowed, here is **74 byte** approach:

```swift
import Foundation
print((1...9).map{Int(pow((pow(10,Double($0))-1)/9,2))})
```

**[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/597a141dfd4af225961bf018)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 22 bytes

```perl
say((1x$_)**2)for 1..9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJDw7BCJV5TS8tIMy2/SMFQT8/y//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Using Jenny_mathy's formula to save a lot of bytes.